# cassandra get all where sth contains sth

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, cql

I am currently writing a spring application. I am searching a way to do a request in cassandra with which I can get all entries by sth as example:

I have the following table:

```
 username | entityid
----------+--------------------------------------
 pascalku | 55f23680-0201-11e8-9971-4516c86aec2e
```

When I am now search for Pascal i wanna get this result.

I tested much cql commandlines but nothing works.

Hope somebody got an idea or know how to do this. Thanks for reading!

EDIT:

My resolver_names:

```
CREATE TABLE resolver_names (
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    entityid uuid
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Please share your table schema, and what kind of queries you have tried, etc. As for now, I assume your primary key is username. If it's true, then you can't do it using native cql query as it's not following cassandra data model.

Comment: And how should i Change it?

Comment: you can use `edit` feature for your original question. More details will help to understand your issue better, and eventually come up with good answer.

Comment: I added the Schema of the Name resolving. I tried stuff like contains, like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `username` is primary key, there is no way to query with `LIKE` operation in cassandra. Kindly note that cassandra is NoSQL database, it's not like relational database, in which you can run such kind of query like `select * from table where comlum1 like '%pascal%'`. I would recommend you to go through free data modeling course [here](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling) for better understanding. In short, if you want to run such kind of queries in your application with cassandra, there might be something wrong when data/table is modelled.

If it's not primary key but just normal column, LIKE queries can be achieved using a SSTable Attached Secondary Index (SASI) in cassandra 3.4 onward. Please refer to [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) for more details.

There are some frameworks, which can be added on top of cassandra to achieve the same (e.g. Spark SQL, etc). However, the performance might not be as good as built-in query, and it's not recommended to so do.